# REST WS connecting to a database

Tags: java, performance, rest, jdbc, jersey

I have a REST WS in Java using Jersey that connects to a database. I don't know what should be the ideal time for execution but I feel the time it takes is too much.

The actual call to DB completes in range of 0-3 milliseconds but the overall time to complete the REST request takes >9 milliseconds.

Here is one of the methods:

```
connection // declared as instance variable
preparedStatement //declared as instance variable 
public int insertSubscription(ActiveWatchers activeWatchers) throws SQLException {

        int index = 0;

        try {
            connection = DAOConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SUBS);
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getPresentityURI());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getCallId());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getToTag());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getFromTag());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getToUser());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getToDomain());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getWatcherUsername());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getWatcherDomain());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getEvent());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getEventId());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getLocalCseq());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getRemoteCseq());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getExpires());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getStatus());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getReason());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getRecordRoute());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getContact());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getLocalContact());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getVersion());
            preparedStatement.setObject(++index, activeWatchers.getSocketInfo());

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int status = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.debug("insertSubscription elasped time {}", (end - start));
            logger.debug("Insert returned with status {}.", status);
            return status;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error("Error while adding new subscription by {}@{} for {} into database.", activeWatchers.getWatcherUsername(), activeWatchers.getWatcherDomain(), activeWatchers.getPresentityURI(), ex);
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while adding new subscription by {}@{} for {} into database.", activeWatchers.getWatcherUsername(), activeWatchers.getWatcherDomain(), activeWatchers.getPresentityURI(), ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            DAOConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection, preparedStatement, null);
        }

    }
```

**The REST part**

```
subscriptionDAO //declared as instance variable
@POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response addSubscription(ActiveWatchers activeWatchers) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.debug("addSubscription start time {}", start);
        subscriptionDAO = new SubscriptionDAO();
        try {
            subscriptionDAO.insertSubscription(activeWatchers);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.debug("addSubscription elasped time {}", (end - start));
            return Response.status(201).build();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while creating subscription.", ex);
            return Response.status(500).entity("Server Error").build();
        }
    }
```

I have a lot of other similar functions for different operations and each has similar behavior which is affecting the overall performance of the system.

Comment: Is the `ActiveWatchers` class trivial? The code you have presented here looks straightforward, and is unlikely to be your bottleneck.

Comment: @200_success ActiveWatchers class is the bean class.

Answer (score 1):

You should try making `insertSubscription` static. You create a new `SubscriptionDAO` object with each request, when all you use it for is a a database handler. It doesn't have any internal state it keeps track of, except for the Connection and the PreparedStatement, which are overwritten inside of the method anyway.

You close the connection at the end of the query, and as such, you could easily make `insertSubscription` static. It'd help with multi-threading as well, if two threads get a hold of the same `SubscriptionDAO` and both do `insertSubscription`, they'd interfere pretty badly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will implement that way. What about `connection` and `preparedStatement` should they be instance\class\local variable. Initially, I made then local but someone said they should be made instance?

Comment: They should be local, there is no way around it if you want a threadsafe static method.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask for a code review in the forum? It's a small project of 8-9 classes and most are similar.